# Four 4k simultaneous playbacks from new Macbook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, graphics, 4k

Is the new 15" Macbook Pro 2018 capable of playing four 4k videos on four 4k displays simultaneously?

Comment: I seriously doubt it. Laptops are not known for their number-crunching ability.

Comment: Mirrored or independent?  If mirrored, why not consider a 4K video splitter?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**.

Although you may be pushing the system to its limits, it's technically possible to drive 4 simultaneous 4K displays using the new 2018 15" MacBook Pro.

From the Video Support section of MacBook Pro [Technical Specifications](https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/specs/) page:

[image]

Comment: It might be able to push 'desktop' or a static app to all those screens at once, but I seriously doubt its ability to send 4 separate video decodes to 4 screens simultaneously.

Comment: How about if I connect a Radeon Vega 64 eGPU?